# Parse XML data into Chart.js Line Chart

Tags: javascript, xml, charts

I'm trying to combine two javascripts into one but am struggling to get it to work. I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible, but I thought stackoverflow is the best place to get help.

The first javascript is [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), specifically the Line Chart option. The second script is an XML in HTML script by [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp).

What I would like to do is using an XML file to populate the data for the line chart. I modified the code accordingly, but I have only very basic knowledge of javascript and couldn't get it to work. This is what I tried:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="350" height="300"></canvas>
<script>
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {    // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","data_chart.xml",false);
   xmlhttp.send();
   xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

   var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Row")
   for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)

   var lineChartData = {
                labels : ["1","2","3","4","5"],
                datasets : [{
                     fillColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                     strokeColor : "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
                     pointColor : "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
                     pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                     data : [x[i].getElementsByTagName("data_chart_1")]
                   }]
           }
   var myLine = new   
   Chart(document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);

</script>
```

So, the idea is that the data section of the variable `lineChartData` is populated by getting all elements in the row `data_chart_1` from the XML file `data_chart.xml`. Is something like this possible? How would I have to update the code to make this work?

Thank you very much for your help. I hope my question was clear.

Comment: `xmlhttp.responseXML` can you show the response?

Comment: Do you mean what is displayed on the page? Basically, it shows the canvas with the grid lines for the graph but it doesn't show the line graph itself (presumably because it can't read the data). I'm sorry if I misunderstood what you meant with the response. In terms of the code, I followed the w3schools example.

Comment: I wanna see your data.xml

Comment: The data is set up this way:


`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Row>
  <data_chart_1>1,2,3,4,5</data_chart_1>
 </Row>
</Root>`

Comment: please check now and get back to me. and try not to use http:.//w3fools.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var firstRow = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Row")[0];
//console.log(firstRow);
var dataChart = firstRow.firstChild.nodeValue;
//console.log(dataChart);
var chartData = dataChart.split(",");
.......................
data : chartData
```

Comment: Yes, this did the job beautifully! Thank you so much for your help naveen!